# Xtick frequency in pandas boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

I am using `pandas groupby` for plotting wind speed Vs direction using  a bar and whisker plot. However the xaxis is not readable due to so many wind direction value close to each other.

I have tried the `oc_params ax.set_xticks` but instead I am having empty x-axis or modified xaxis with different values

The head of my dataframe

```
    Kvit_TIU     dir_cat  
0   0.064740         14  
1   0.057442         15  
2   0.056750         15  
3   0.069002         17  
4   0.068464         17  
5   0.067057         17  
6   0.071901         12  
7   0.050464          5  
8   0.066165          1  
9   0.073993         27  
10  0.090784         34  
11  0.121366         33  
12  0.087172         34  
13  0.066197         30  
14  0.073020         17  
15  0.071784         16  
16  0.081699         17  
17  0.088014         14  
18  0.076758         14  
19  0.078574         14
```

I used `groupby = dir_cat` to create a box plot

```py
fig = plt.figure() # create the canvas for plotting
ax1 = plt.subplot(1,1,1) 
ax1 = df_KvTr10hz.boxplot(column='Kvit_TIU', by='dir_cat', showfliers=False, showmeans=True)
ax1.set_xticks([30,90, 180,270, 330])
```

I would like to have the x-axis plotted with a reduced frequency. So that the plot can be readable
[image: unreadable plot]
[image: using ax1.set_xticks]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Kvit_TIU   dir_cat  
0  0.064740       14  
1  0.057442       14  
2  0.056750       15  
3  0.069002       15  
4  0.068464       17

Answer (score 0):

```
 ax1 = df_KvTr10hz.dropna().boxplot(column='Kvit_TIU', by='dir_cat', showfliers=False, showmeans=True)
```

EDIT: Using OP sample dataframe

[image: sample]

However, if we substitute with NaNs the `Kvit_TIU` values for `'dir_cat'>=30`

[image: samplewithNaN]

Comment: Hi Gio thanks for the reply. It does not change anything

Comment: after you created the plot, can you type `ax1.get_xlim()` and tell me the output? Do not run `ax1.set_xlim`

Comment: This is the output (0.5, 37.5)

Comment: so it seems to me that you have a large number of categories (37) but I would assume that all the data is concentrated in the first couple and the others are empty or something similar. Try the following: `ax1.set_xlim(0, 2)` or `ax1.set_xlim(0, 4)`

Comment: I have value in the complete range from (0,37) as illustrated in the ax1.get_xlim(). The x-axis is plotted with intervals of 1. I want it to be plotted with interval of 3 so that the figure can be readable. using ax1.set_xlim(0, 4) just gives me one part of the figure unfortunately

Comment: @Zak Please post a sample dataframe to reproduce your problem

Comment: I just added a sample

Comment: @Zak can't replicate your problem. works fine for me

Comment: @Zak check updated answer, I keep thinking you have NaNs or empty categories